# Make NSolve faster by keeping only one solution

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

`NSolve` usually returns all numerical solution it can find. When a variable is squared in some equation, `NSolve` will always returns both positive and negative solutions. For example:

```
NSolve[x^2 == 1, x]
(* {{x -> -1.}, {x -> 1.}} *)
```

With more variables, `NSolve` will return all possible combinations of their sign.

I am trying to find a $16*16$ semidefinite positive hermitian matrix $M_{lik}$ that as the best Likelihood with a $16*16$ hermitian data matrix $M_{data}$. I know that because of Cholesky decomposition, there is a $16*16$ lower triangular matrix $L$ that satisfies: $M_{lik} = L L^{\dagger}$. The diagonal elements of $L$ must be real (so that $Tr(M_{lik})=1$), the extra-diagonals can be complex.
Before starting my numerical Maximum Likelihood optimization, I would like to initialize $L$ the best I could using $M_{data}$. I know there is an exact solution to compute the elements of $L$ from the elements of $M_{lik}$ as stated in [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.64.052312).

Two solutions are possible:

- extend the formula in the paper from $4*4$ to $16*16$ and compute the elements of $L$ from $M_{data}$. This solution will give complex numbers on $L$ diagonal, which is normal as $M_{data}$ is not semidefinite positive. One can drop the unwanted imaginary parts and use this result as an initial guess for $L$. (That is what the paper does)
- be lazy and ask *Mathematica* to `NSolve` a system of quadratic polynomials with $16*16$ real variables, drop the unwanted imaginary parts and proceed.

I do the following:

```
PosMat[d_] := Module[{Mat, L},
  Mat = ArrayReshape[Table[ele[i], {i, d^2}], {d, d}];
  L = LowerTriangularize[Mat + I Transpose[UpperTriangularize[Mat, 1]]];
  ComplexExpand[LMat.ConjugateTranspose[LMat]]
 ]
d = 16;
sols = NSolve[PosMat[d] == Mdata, Table[ele[i], {i, d^2}]];
```

The problem is: `NSolve` takes a very long time and returns $2^{16}$ set of solutions of the `ele[i]` because the equations are quadratic. Each set contains the values of the $16*16=256$ `ele[i]`.

Can I help `NSolve` by telling it to keep only the first set of solution that comes up and stop ? Should I try to look for real solutions only and decrease `WorkingPrecision` to $1$ or $2$ to hope to catch an approximate solution?

**LATE CONCLUSION:**
The problem was about getting Mathematica's `NSolve` to stop computing all solutions to a system of equations after one solution is found. Unfortunately, I could not find a way to force `NSolve` to stop and using it was then too time-consuming.
The plan was to use the solution provided by `NSolve` as an initial guess for another standard optimization algorithm. Unfortunately, this other algorithm (based on Mathematica's `FindMinimum` function) was unable to withstand the scale of the problem. I eventually solved this with an Evolutionary Strategy that could tackle the scale and did not required an initial guess.

Comment: You know `CholeskyDecomposition[]` is built-in, right?

Comment: I do ! But if I try `L=CholeskyDecomposition[Mdata]`, Mathematica raises `CholeskyDecomposition::posdef` error because `"The matrix {<<1>>} is not sufficiently positive definite to complete the Cholesky decomposition to reasonable accuracy.`.
Indeed, $M_{data}$ is not semidefinite positive because it comes from measurements from the real world, thus contains statistical and experimental errors and can be seen as "unphysical". Otherwise I would not need a Maximum Likelihood Estimator to find a "physical" matrix.

Comment: (1) Could try using `FindRoot` instead of `NSolve`. (2) Would it help to do Cholesky on `Mdata+epsilon*IdentityMatrix[...]` for suitablly small positive `epsilon`?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: `FindRoot` requires an initial guess which I am actually looking for :-)
With an approximate constant matrix and `MaxIterations -> 10000` it spits out a solution as well as a `FindRoot::lstol` error. The reason is: `The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.`
I need to assess the quality of this solution.
For (2) I don't know yet. Work under progress.

Comment: Would be helpful to have complete code to replicate the problem.

Comment: Recap: I was able to produce an initial guess using the Cholesky decomposition as @DanielLichtblau suggested. Unfortunately, the dimension of the problem (now 25²) forced me to move to other algorithms.
I ended up using an Evolutionary Strategy to solve this problem. Works like a charm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP found another way to solve the problem and did not share it by posting a self-answer.